# tte vs to as quotation markers?

Tags: particles, particle-と, particle-って

I've been taught here that "to" is used sometimes as quotation marker. Now I've read in a website that "tte" is used for indirect speech and what seems to be quotation too? If so, when should I use "to" and when "tte" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply, "tte" is for casual speech and therefore mostly used with family and close friends. "to" is the proper form you should use.